# Using a ONE WORD javascript variable in form field VALUES

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I have a function that gets values from a the URL and then posts it to various places on the page.

I can't figure out how to get the values to read inside form field values.

```
<OPTION Value="<script type="text/javascript">document.write(Position)
</script> has final say">
```

I know I can't do that specifically, but I've tried various configurations and nothing posts the variable inside the value field.

The document.write function is working on the plain html, I have tested that. I just don't know to make it read inside a form field value and display the results properly.

How do I get one word to display as a variable, without having to create a function that inputs the value of each field. There are way too many fields to make that viable -  this needs to populate into maybe 200 or 300 variables, so I really need it to be the word.

The site is standalone so I can't use php as I understand it. If there's a way I'm open to it. I did try the php echo to call the field name but I don't know enough about php to know if I'm missing something.

I am open to solutions where I can upload files into the standalone site though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some more sample of your code so we can better understanding what you're working with? Like the function that gets the values from the URL..etc

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is get this to read inside a form field value, but print the value when the form posts the results.

`code` <script type="text/javascript">document.write(Position)
</script>

That field calls one word of a sentence.

Comment: Please update your question above to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: That really is the whole problem... the document.write function calls perfectly to everywhere else on my page but I don't know how to structure the code to get it to replace one word in the form field values.

That is the whole problem, everything else is working fine.

How do I call a ONE WORD variable into a form field VALUE. I can get it in the html, and it's fine - how do I populate it to fields?

I can't wrap a <script type="text/javascript">document.write(Position)
</script> around it like I do in plain html.

Short of uploading the website I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks - the solution below solved the problem :) Your input was appreciated :)

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are stuck writing code only on the client-side, then you may want to use a client-side library like jQuery to help you manage your DOM manipulation.

For example, you can set a class for every variable you want to set and then use jQuery to replace the contents of those elements.

```js
var values = {
  position: "top",
  name: "steve"
}
$(".position").text(values.position).val(values.position)
$(".name").text(values.name).val(values.name)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="position"></option>
  <option class="name"></option>
</select>
<select>
  <option class="name"></option>
</select>
<select>
  <option class="position"></option>
</select>
<select>
  <option class="position"></option>
  <option class="name"></option>
  <option class="position"></option>
  <option class="name"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi - I've no idea how to that and the places it populates to are variable. So each dropdown has maybe 6 to 10 options, and the sentence structure is different on each option.

So it's easier to use a variable that calls the one word. 

If I do it by input id value, I would have to create a function for every option on every dropdown. That would be a ridiculous amount - the form already has 200 fields, and then multiple options per most field. I'd land up with a function set longer than the website LOL :)

Comment: jquery will select ALL of the elements that share the same class, so in this example, 200 different option elements with the class `"position"` would all get selected and updated by that one line of code, I will update the answer to show this

Comment: Okay so if I'm understanding you I put the line in, include the file and then give every option that needs to be updated that class? 

Will it automatically happen on pageload (the variables are fetched from the URL), or will I have to do something to trigger that? 

About to try this - sounds like a very elegant solution. Thank you. Will feedback shortly :)

Comment: it won't happen on pageload, you will need to listen for that event in your own script, if you are interested in learning jQuery you might find [these docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) useful

Comment: Thank you - by combining your solution with a a document.write in the label it works flawlessly. 

truly appreciated - spent the better part of today trying to figure this out :)

Comment: Hi :) 

I have a quick question, how do I adjust the variable for a checkbox? 

My checkboxes go via this code.... 
`code` var favorite64 = []; $.each($("input[name='Position64']:checked"), function(){favorite64.push($(this).val());});

It displays the result as the word on. How do I change that?

Thank you again :) Can't tell you how much I love this fix :)

Comment: you should probably ask a new question for that one, and include a little more code and context

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
var position = 'helloworld'
document.getElementById('id1').options[0].value=position;
```

```html
<select id="id1">
<option>The Value is the POSITION variable.</option>
</select>
```

I added an ID to the select box (`<select id="id1">`). Then you can use the script to insert the `position` variable as the value of the options within the select.

If this is not what you're looking for then you really need to update your question with more sample from your code (i.e some HTML would be nice).

Comment: I did find a solution thanks. 

It really is a straightforward question about how I code the syntax for the variable when calling it from javascript, how I make it render in the results display without blocking the formatting. 

So basically how to make the results display accept the printed value on the page - the printing is working perfectly - how do I change that piece of javascript code so that it will place a one word variable into a line of text that is form field value?

The question is truly about the scripting of that syntax :)